# Django при сохранении файла вместо имени файла предлагает текущий url

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Ответственный кусок кода:

```
work_fname='файл имя.расширение'
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    response = HttpResponse(f.read(), content_type='') 
    Content_Disposition = 'attachment; filename='+work_fname
    response['Content-Disposition'] = Content_Disposition
    response['Content-Type'] = 'charset=utf-16'
    return response
```

Страница сохранения находится по адресу `mysite.ru/save_confirmed`.В окне сохранения браузера в поле имени файла выводится почему-то не `файл имя.расширение`, а текущий URL: `save_confirmed`. В смысле файл хочет сохраниться под именем `save_confirmed`.

Пробовал:

```
Content_Disposition = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(work_fname)
```

Пробовал:

```
response = HttpResponse(f.read(), content_type='application/force-download')
```

Все варианты с кавычками и без тоже пробовал.

Comment: Если имя файла на eng, то всё работает. Кириллицей - возникает описанный косяк. Повторяется при запуске джанги под Win7 и на VPS под Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

Взять тут:

```
from django.utils.encoding import iri_to_uri
```

Сделать так:

```
Content_Disposition = 'attachment; filename={}'.format(iri_to_uri(filename))
```

Chrome, Opera, Yandex - ОК, в Лисе кракозябры.